# Firebase Data Filtering

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following `Firebase` `JSON` data structure;

```
  {
  "USERS": {
    "YjGJsvCb58OsTThv6JLmK1dMuHr1": {
      "Email": "test@test.com"
    },
    "zQpb7o18VzYsSoTQtT9DNhOqTUn2": {
      "Email": "test2@test.com"
    }
  },
  "POSTS": {
    "-KSe4eJyenccPoC5T0zP": {
      "addedByUser": "YjGJsvCb58OsTThv6JLmK1dMuHr1",
      "content": "Post 1",
      "cost": "600",
      "duration": "Quarterly",
      "latitude": "51.5099850000001",
      "longitude": "-0.133528614416432",
      "timestamp": "Tue 27 Sep"
    },
    "-KSe4q1DXoulArzWm_Zm": {
      "addedByUser": "YjGJsvCb58OsTThv6JLmK1dMuHr1",
      "content": "Post 2",
      "cost": "550",
      "duration": "Monthly",
      "latitude": "51.5100199999855",
      "longitude": "-0.133507191218496",
      "timestamp": "Tue 27 Sep"
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to filter `POSTS` and get all `POSTS` that have `duration` as `Monthly` or whichever the user has selected. As you can see each `POST` is assigned an `AutoID`.

The result Im looking for should spit out:

```
  {
  "-KSe4q1DXoulArzWm_Zm": {
    "addedByUser": "YjGJsvCb58OsTThv6JLmK1dMuHr1",
    "content": "Post 2",
    "cost": "550",
    "duration": "Monthly",
    "latitude": "51.5100199999855",
    "longitude": "-0.133507191218496",
    "timestamp": "Tue 27 Sep"
  }
}
```

But I cannot, for the life of me, search through the `AutoID`s.  I have tried near enough all the `queryFor` & `observe` methods.  I've searched through StackOverflow and no solution seems to work.  Have I structured my data correctly? The reason I need the `AutoID` is that some of the posts may be the same.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().queryOrdered(byChild: "POSTS").queryEqual(toValue: "monthly").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snap) in


    if let postsDict = snap.value as! [String:AnyObject]{

       for each in postsDict {

          print(each)

            }

    }else{

    //That username doesnt exists.

    }

})
```

Comment: Accept it as answer if it solved your issue:)Happy Coding